# getExternalFilesDir returns different paths on differen devices

Tags: android

Please help me to solve a problem. My applications allows to take photo and save it in private folder. Below i describe steps which i've done (by the official documentation).

I add permissions and provider in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-premission andoird:name="andoird.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
    <application ...>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.company.appname.fileprovider"
            ...>
            <meta-data
                android:name="andoird.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                andoird:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

in the file_path.xml, i've added a required path

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/com.company.appname/file/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

then i run cameraIntent after permission for the camera was requested (kotlin)

```
fun cameraIntent() {
    var intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packecgeManager) != null) {
        val prefix = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
        var suffix = ".jpg"
        val folder = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) // (1)
        var file = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, folder) // (2)
        var uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.company.appname.fileprovider", file) // (1.1)
        ...
    }
}
```

And finally the problem descriptions.

**(1)** this code sometimes returns path as set in file_path.xml

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.appname/file/Pictures/1534529847360260979036.jpg
```

but sometimes (Lenovo A6010/Android 5.0.2/API 21)

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.appname/cache/1534529847360260979036.jpg
```

**(1.1)** as result of (1), when result path refers to 'cache', this line of code throws the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException 
Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.company.appname/cache/1534529847360260979036.jpg
```

because this path is not set in file_path, but **why (1) returns this path?**

**(2)** This line of code sometimes throws exception too (HUAWEI ShotX/5.1.1/API 22)

```
java.io.IOException 
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

**Why?**

PS: minSdkVersion for my application is 21.

Comment: `/data/data/` refers to internal storage, not external storage. Your reported output does not match your code (let alone your `FileProvider` configuration). Regardless, if you have a device that is giving you trouble, see whether the problem is `getExternalFilesDir()` or `File.createTempFile()`. My guess is that the problem comes from `File.createTempFile()`, in which case you could use something else to create a unique filename inside of your desired directory.

Comment: the main problem is `getExternalFilesDir()` returns path with _cache_, not _files_. `FileProvider` throws exception as result of it. And my question: **Why does this function return unexpected path?**

Comment: You should ask the manufacturer of course. I never saw getExternalFilesDir() return an internal path.

Comment: `val folder = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` That folder will not normally exist on an Android device. You are not checking existence or creating that folder but blindly try to create a file in it.

Comment: it is my mistake, `getExternalFilesDir()` returns the other path, i change path in the question

Comment: @greenapps, it is not a problem. Problem in different path on different devices. I pass this path to camera intent and convert given path to _content://_ path. When this method returns a _cache_ path, it is not converted to _content://_ path, but throws unexpected exception.

Comment: Then adapt your file provider paths.

Comment: "Why does this function return unexpected path?" -- Lenovo screwed up, apparently.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there a normal warkaround to solve such troubles? I can't save photos to cache, it will be removed when user clear cache. How do android developers solve such problems?

Comment: If you are using `FileProvider`, to me there is no obvious benefit to using `getExternalFilesDir()` over `getFilesDir()`. So, you might switch to that. Or, see what `getExternalFilesDir(null)` returns.

Answer (score 0):

i change the path generating by the following way

```
var folder = getExternalFilesDir(null)
if (folder.path.endsWith("cache")) {
    folder = File(folder.path.replace("cache", "files"))
}
if (!folder.exists()) {
    folder.mkdir()
}
folder = File(folder.path + File.separator + "Pictures")
if (!folder.exists()) {
    folder.mkdir()
}
val file = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, folder)
...
```

I think it's an ugly solution, but i havn't any other ideas.